# Change/update a model in runtime

Tags: qooxdoo

I want to change/update a model in run time which is created with

`var model = qx.data.marshal.Json.createModel(def.model)` .

and binding textfields with object controller which is created with this

`var controller = new qx.data.controller.Object(model)`

How to do it? `de.model` is a JSON definition for model which is look like this :

```
{
     f_name: "baskar",
     l_name: "vignesh"
}
```

for example I want to add `address` field with this existing model.
so

```
{
     f_name: "baskar",
     l_name: "vignesh",
     address: "blah blah blah"
}
```

How to do it? anyone please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As models are instances of dynamically created classes, that's not possible. You can not change a class in place and with that, all instances of it. The way to go would be to create a new model and copy the data over. Thats the only possible way I can think of right now.

Comment: Ok. Thanks Martin. Thanks for your reply. Nice library.